# tricky css positioning question

Tags: css

my `body` has a tiled background (blueness in attached image)

I need to horizontally centre some fixed width and height content (greenness), a fixed distance from the top of the page.

I then need to continue the background image of the centred content to the left and right extremities of the page, however wide the browser is (the purple)

The reason for this is that the green content has a "hole" in it, which allows the `body` background to show through. If this wasnt a requirement id make the purpleness a 100% width div which wraps the content, and simply give it the tiled background image.

[image]

So far i've managed this:

```
<div id="Left"></div>
<div id="Right"></div>
<div id="Content"></div>


#Left
{
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: 480px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 50%;
    height: 525px;
    background: transparent url(/images/purple.png) repeat-x scroll center top;
}
#Right
{
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 480px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    height: 525px;
    background: transparent url(/images/purple.png) repeat-x scroll center top;
}

#Content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -480px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 525px;
    background: transparent url(/images/green.png) no-repeat scroll center top;
}
```

Which *does* work, except the page has a horizontal scroll bar with the right hand purpleness extending for some way. How can i overcome this?

I can't spoof the hole by simply duplicating the background, and i'd like to avoid putting an `overflow-x: hidden` on the body.

**Edit:** I also need to have a variable height page, as the given `525px height` may be much larger and therefore the page will need to v-scroll.

This needs to work in IE7+, FF, Safari

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick:

```
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">

body
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#Left
{
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: 480px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 50%;
    height: 5525px;
    border: solid 2px purple;
}
#Right
{
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 480px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    height: 5525px;
    border: solid 2px purple;
}

#Content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -480px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 5525px;
    border: solid 2px green;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="Left"></div>
<div id="Right"></div>
<div id="Content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I added styles to the body tag (to prevent the horizontal scroll bar), and I used a margin of "auto" on the Content div (not sure if it is necessary, but that is how I would do it).

Let me know if there's something I missed.

EDIT:

I put the absolute positioning back on the content div. GD you Internet Explorer...

Comment: this works, but this also removes the vertical scroll bar if anything goes below the page fold (admittedly the original question doesnt stipulate this). is there a way around this?

Comment: @Stargazer712... that wouldn't work. The Left and Right `<div>`s are both 50% which means they would cover all of the area which means the background image 'green.png' would have a purple hole in the middle, not blue.

Comment: @Andrew... ahh I missed that part. Sorry!

Comment: @Andrew: Replacing "overflow:hidden" with "overflow-x:hidden" works on every browser I checked (FF3 and IE6).

Comment: @Stargazer i thought overflow-x was css3? im seeing some really weird behaviour in IE (surprise surprise) your html above works, mine set up the same doesnt. if i copy the above html over mine exactly and refresh, _that_ doesnt work!!!, bloody IE!!!!!

Comment: I am not sure on the overflow-x, but it works in IE6, so it can't be CSS3. I copied and pasted the exact code that I am using to say that it works (note the borders instead of background images).

Answer (score 0):

usually I can get around this by setting:

```
#content{
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

You can do away with Left and Right then (unless of course you want to keep them).

Then to get the hole just make the background of the content a png image and make the hole transparent. It'll appear transparent on the div then.

Comment: I do want to keep them, the purple is a continuation of the green image. "I then need to continue the background image of the centred content to the left and right extremities of the page, however wide the browser is (the purple)"

Comment: Perhaps you can add {width:25%; float:left;} and {width:25%; float:right;} onto the Purple divs to keep them where they aught to be

Comment: You may have to mess with the rather fiddly positioning on that one though

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<style>
body {
    background: blue;
    margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
}
#left {
    background: magenta;
    height: 300px;
    margin-right: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#center {
    border: 100px solid lime;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: -300px;
    width: 400px;
}
#right {
    background: magenta;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

- I used absolute positioning for the left side, since you never get a scrollbar there anyway.
- I floated the center div, so I could use [the "secret benefit" of overflow](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/07/23/overflow-a-secret-benefit/) to fill out the right side of the screen without creating a scrollbar.
- I used a border to the center div to show that the body's blue background does indeed "show through", but you can of course use a background image instead.

(I tested it in Firefox 3.6 and IE8 in IE8 and IE7 modes.)